# String interpolation not replacing with actual value in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to replace value of a Yaml file with `yq` and global variable declared in my jenkins.groovy script. The Code does not throw any error but it is not replacing the values and Yaml remains unchanged.

```
stage('Clone abc repository and prepare abc-installer') {
                agent { label LABEL_CICD }
                steps {
                  
                    sshagent(credentials:['jenkins-deploy-password']) {

                        sh 'whoami; PWD=$(pwd); SCRIPT_DIR=${PWD}/installer; \
                       
                        yq -i \'.abc-server.image.tag = $IMAGE_TAG\' ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/values-single.yaml; \
                        cat ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/values-single.yaml; \
                        yq -i \'.spec.source.targetRevision = $ARGO_TARGETREVISION\' ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/abc.yaml; \
                        cat ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/abc.yaml; \
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using double quotes for String interpolation to work.

```
sh """
whoami; PWD=$(pwd); SCRIPT_DIR=${PWD}/installer; \
                       
                        yq -i \'.abc-server.image.tag = $IMAGE_TAG\' ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/values-single.yaml; \
                        cat ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/values-single.yaml; \
                        yq -i \'.spec.source.targetRevision = $ARGO_TARGETREVISION\' ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/abc.yaml; \
                        cat ${SCRIPT_DIR}/manifests/abc/abc.yaml;
"""
```